# New different browser launched during the protractor test

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Is there a way to open new different browser during the test? For example I open a page in chrome I take screenshot and then I open firefox take screenshot of the same page and compare them. Or maybe there is a possibility to specify the browser in test after configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't understand your question but why don't you run in Multi capabilities? you can run in GC and Firefox in the same time and then do what you need to do

```
multiCapabilities: [
{
browserName: 'firefox',
}, 
{
browserName: 'chrome',
chromeOptions: {
  args: [
      '--start-maximized'
        ]
}
}],
```

You can set the command to take a screen shot and will be done for both

```
// at the top of the test spec:
var fs = require('fs');

// abstract writing screen shot to a file
function writeScreenShot(data, filename) {
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    stream.write(new Buffer(data, 'base64'));
    stream.end();
}

// ...

// within a test:
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
    writeScreenShot(png, 'FileName.png');
});
```

Comment: I changed to  multiCapabilities, but when i run test it only opens two browsers and do nothing.. maybe you know what is the issue ?

Comment: Ok i solved it. I had to move 
`require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e'
    });` 
form beforeLunch  to onPrepare